# F# This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'

Tags: f#, unit-type

I have the following code

```
if somecondition then
  myobj.Property1 = match myobj.Property1 with
                       | null -> SomePropertyType ()
                       | p -> p
```

What I am trying to do is to see if myobj.Property1 is null, if it is not then leave it alone otherwise create a new object of type SomePropertyType and assign it.

Problem is, I am getting a

```
This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'
```

And what should I do If I had to put multiple of those myobj.Property1 .... statements under that `if` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are comparing two values (using `=`) so the return type will be `bool`, but if you have an if without else the compiler expect `unit` as return type.

I guess you intended to assign the value to the property, use `<-` instead:

```
if somecondition then
    myobj.Property1 <- match myobj.Property1 with ...
```

Anyway if you want to check for `null` to assign a default value you don't need a `match`, an `if` `then` is enough:

```
if somecondition then
    if (myobj.Property1 = null) then myobj.Property1 <- SomePropertyType ()
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

You can "merge" both `if` .. `then` to a single `match`:

```
match (somecondition, myobj.Property1) with
| true, null -> myobj.Property1 <- SomePropertyType ()
...
```

Comment: I know but I like my code to look "functional" and if-else make it procedural rather functional.

Comment: @fahadash Changing a single if then to a match will not make it more functional. In pure functional languages if then else is a function as well. Changing MANY if then to a SINGLE match is another story. See the update.